# "Unknown custom element: <router-link>" Upgraded to Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Upgraded an app from vue 1 and vue-router 0.7 and getting this error in the console

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option. 
>   (found in component ...[path to component  is called in]

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import gsap from 'gsap';

Vue.use( VueResource );
Vue.use( VueRouter );

window.flipster = require( 'jquery.flipster' );
window.spritespin = require('SpriteSpin');

// Main Layout Components
import Menu from './components/Menu.vue';
import Section from './components/Section.vue';

// Controller Layout Components
import ControllerMenu from './components/Controller/Menu.vue';
import ControllerSection from './components/Controller/Section.vue';

// Generic Components
import Tabs from './components/Tabs.vue';
Vue.component( 'tabs', Tabs );

import Tab from './components/Tab.vue';
Vue.component( 'tab', Tab );

import Chart from './components/Chart.vue';
Vue.component( 'chart', Chart );

import ChartDev from './components/ChartDev.vue';

import Datastore from './DataStore';
Vue.use( Datastore );

// controller check and other useful functionality
import Helpers from './Helpers';
Vue.use( Helpers );

import App from './App.vue';

window.eventHub = new Vue();

var router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'menu',
            component: ControllerMenu
        },
        {
            path: 'sections/:sectionId',
            name: 'section',
            component: ControllerSection
        },
        {
            path: 'chart/:datasetId',
            name: 'chart',
            component: ChartDev
        }
    ]
});

new Vue({
    router: router,
    render( createElement ) {
        return createElement( App )
    }
}).$mount( '.container' );
```

The routes themselves work fine if I navigate to them using the address bar, it's just that `router-link` component not being a thing.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean: router-link component not being a thing?

Answer (score 7):

You are not initializing the router using `Vue.use`. You need to do the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

Ref: https://router.vuejs.org/en/installation.html

**EDIT: More thoughts after comments #1 and #2:**

You are mounting the app using `.$mount( '.container' )`. While this can work as expected, using a class selector is risky. Are you sure you have only one `<div class="container">` element? You can possibly try using an id selector in a much more simplified way as in docs:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    router: router,
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

While this has nothing to do with `router-link` being unavailable, I suspect there could be multiple instances of Vue, if you have multiple `container` elements. Other than the above, I cannot find anything else wrong with the code.

Comment: Sorry, I left that part out of the question because it's boilerplate stuff. It is there and as I said, the router itself is working. I can navigate around using the URL and it loads the correct components.

It's just when I try to use router-view component in my template I run into the issue.

Comment: `Vue.use` calls the `install` method of a plugin as [defined in docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-use). The install method of vue-router contains the line `Vue.component('router-link', Link)` just after defining `router-view`. So, the `router-link` should get defined and be available. I will get back if I can find some other issue in your modified question.

Comment: Used an id selector just to be safe but as you said, no difference. Thanks for try though

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something went wrong when you updated vue-router, are you definately using the correct version? Try running `npm list vue-router` from within your project root and it should output a 2.0.x version:

> vue-router@2.0.3

anything less than v2 wouldn't have router-link, if this is the case try:

```
npm uninstall vue-router
npm install vue-router --save-dev
```

---

If the version is correct then may be worth simplifying the project to troubleshoot this. I made a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/thebigsurf/ajpuw8hq/

If you copy across the html & js from this basic set up does it fix the issue? If so it may be that one of your other `Vue.use()` plugin configs is breaking vue-router.

Comment: I think you got it right. Johnathan mentioned that he upgraded to Vue2 recently. So he needs to upgrade vue-router also.

Comment: Definitely using vue-router 2.0.3. Confirmed with `npm list`

Comment: ok cool - I updated answer with a simple example app to help you troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 2):

For anybody who is using Jest and doesn't want to do any testing around `router-link` - but want to rid of the compilation error - simply stub it out:

```
    wrapper = shallowMount(Flow, {
        propsData: {},
        mocks: {},
        stubs: ['router-view'], // add this
        store,
        localVue,
    });
```